# How can I see who voted down 20-25 questions of mine yesterday?

Tags: discussion, reputation

How can I see who voted down for me?

Someone just voted down 20-25 questions that I have asked and made me -250 to the amount of points (So it might be more than 20...) and even though I don't mind the points at all and prefer to give all of them to the lovely guys who keep help me, It's kind of annoying me.

Edit: He might went through about half of my questions, come to think about that. poor guy.

and it doesn't really matter, you know who you are- get a life.

Thanks.

Comment: You obviously can't. However posting here will let the moderators know that something like that has taken place. As for the reputation lost, the computer generally takes note of such behavior and undoes it later on.

Comment: O.k, cool. but I don't want to do anything with that, and cause a damage to this person. I just want him to know, that he shouldn't do this again and he should know that it's a really poor action.

Comment: Your [reputation summary](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/6163/nir?tab=reputation) doesn't show any such thing (or it has already been corrected  by the software spotting "irregular voting patterns"). Have you maybe forgotten about the 500 points bounty you awarded to Pierre-Yves Gaillard?

Comment: No, I didn't forget that. I had yesterday about 250 points more, after awarding Pierre, and even here, and meta, It shows (for some reason) -250 points from yesterday.

Comment: It really happened, it doesn't show in my reputation summary, all the +1 that this person gave me during the period of time that i'm in the site just disappeared  and you don't get notification about that in the reputation summary.

Comment: What also could be: Your awarding the bounty (or something else) has triggered a recalculation of your reputation which is subject to dropping due to that (e.g. some users who voted on your questions were deleted). This comes up every now and then, e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/recurring-discrepancies-in-rep), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/7327/beni-bogosel) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/how-did-i-lose-rep). You'll have to wait for a moderator to drop by for a better founded answer.

Comment: @Theo: When I started the bounty I immediately saw -500 to the reputation which brought me to 1320 or something.. never mind, I don't want to spend time about this.

Comment: You can't simply remove votes. Already five minutes after you cast your vote the vote is locked in and you can only change it if the post was modified afterwards. Your scenario seems rather implausible to me for these reasons. But, as I said previously *if* it should have happened, I'm with you. (I didn't see your previous comment before posting this one).

Comment: $Theo:Ok, thanks.

Comment: The -250 can't come from downvotes (as one downvote only causes -2 rep), but you already said it came from the _disappearance of upvotes_. (That would need 50 upvotes to questions for 250 rep.) Theo is right, one can't simply remove upvotes. But it can happen that an account is removed, and then all the votes that came from this account are removed, too.

Comment: Now It keeps going up! someone is voting up lots of questions of mine.. what's going on?!

Comment: @Nir: I hope you didn't think that I caused either of these anomalies; I didn't.

Comment: I am somewhat disappointed that a removed acoount leads to a remove of the votes coming from that account. This practice is neither fair nor understandable for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Reputation is denormalized, which means it is not perfectly in sync with "right now" all the time. For example, deletion of users, questions, and answers are not immediately reflected in your reputation score, among other things. see https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation for a live value and there is a recalc option there if you wish to sync it. Note that this will cause some fluctuation in your reputation as it is brought into line with the present state of math.se reality.
2. There is a daily vote anomaly check which looks for and removes any statistical voting anomalies on any account -- either up or down. This indeed did trigger for your account on the 18th.

Note that #2 also by necessity triggers the very same rep recalc as indicated in #1, so it can cause you to "lose" reputation you didn't actually *have*.

Answer (score 3):

One other possibility is that somehow your *real* reputation fell out of line of the *displayed* reputation, and something triggered a complete reputation recomputation on your account. Which will then display the "corrected" reputation. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/recurring-discrepancies-in-rep for example. That link also includes a link to https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation which you can use to audit your own reputation. While it doesn't show who voted what, you can use it to quickly check whether the drop came from downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the bottom of the main page, you'll see a little "contact us" link. I believe that gets you through to the moderators, and that's the right way to deal with the situation. If someone is doing you wrong, and that person never reads meta, what good does it do to post here?

Comment: I have a feeling that he does. Thanks Gerry!